# How do I convert object to float in panda using lambda and apply

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I need to use apply and lambda to convert "Ping (ms)" and "Download (Mbit/s)" from object type to float type. Both columns contain decimal numbers.

Thank you,

I don't get any error but it doesn't convert!

```
# Code Cell 14
# this disables a notebook warning that is not relevant for our use case
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
#df_compact.dtypes
# Convert Ping and Download to float
df_compact_clean["Ping (ms)_float"]=df_compact["Ping (ms)"].apply(lambda row:float)
)
df_compact_clean["Download (Mbit/s)_float"] =df_compact["Download (Mbit/s)"].apply(lambda row: float)
```

Comment: Search for `df.convert_dtypes()`

Comment: if you want to use lamba then with `()`  like `apply(lambda row: float(row))`. Or directly `apply(float)` without `lambda` and `()`. But it may need rather `as_type(float)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `lambda` then you need function with `()`

```
.apply(lambda row: float(row))
```

if you use it without `lambda` then use function without `()`

```
.apply(float)
```

but you could use

```
.astype(float)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'B': ['4', '5', '6'],
    'C': ['7', '8', '9']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda row: float(row))
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(float)
df['C'] = df['C'].astype(float)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to format float pandas series to int pandas series, yo can reuse for any kind of data:

```
for col,items in DataFrame.iteritems():
    colitems = DataFrame[col]
    if colitems.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x,float) ).any() == True:
        DataFrame[col] = DataFrame[col].astype(int)
```